# Как людей из бывшего Союза называют сейчас?

Tags: словоупотребление, одним-словом

Как людей из бывшего Союза называют сейчас? Фразу "Люди из бывшего Советского Союза" неудобно использовать, когда хотите называть эту группу. Также, когда хотите назвать одного человека, которого жил в Союзе, тоже неуклюжно сказать "Человек из бывшего Союза." Должно быть одно слово для этого. Мы с друзьями используем слово "совок," но это просто из-за того, что я начинал это слово так использовать. Я знаю, что "совок" это человек, который верит в систему коммунизма, и это слово не очень приличное.  Но мне "совок" звучит правильно, потому что слово начинается с частью "советский," и конец как существительное слово.

Comment: Слово "совок" совершенно не о том. "Совком", как правило, называют человека, всех достающего показной ностальгией по СССР (либо, в более широком смысле - носителя отрицательных качеств характера, якобы, свойственных жителям СССР). Зачастую, такие люди ничего не знают о, собственно, коммунизме. Можно родиться в СССР, но не быть "совком", а можно наоборот.

Comment: Неуклюже, not неуклюжно .  And, unfortunately, there is no single word for ex-soviet people.

Comment: A вам действительно важно донести до собеседника, родился ли какой-либо человек в стране, которая была в составе СССР 30 лет назад, или нет? Советский Союз распался давным-давно, и, как мне кажется, характеризовать людей по тому, была ли их страна в Советском Союзе или нет, зачастую совсем не обязательно (если, конечно, вы не говорите об истории). Во многих ситуациях существуют более точные и современные категории, обобщающие людей по месту проживания или культурно-лингвистическим особенностям, как-то: русскоязычные, киевляне, казахстанцы, чеченцы и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Варианты

> Граждане бывшего СССР
>  
>   Бывшие граждане СССР 
>  
>   Бывшие советские люди (*более примитивный вариан*т) 
>   Бывшие советские 
>   Граждане СНГ (*хотя СНГ существует больше на бумаге, чем в действительности*)

Насколько мне известно, на русском стандартного термина не существует, возможно потому, что у самих бывших граждан СССР, в отличие от иностранцев, нет необходимости называть себя в третьем лице.

"Совки" это конечно оскорбительно, тем более, что не все бывшие граждане СССР соответствуют этому определению.

---

<sup>И, пользуясь случаем, поправлю вашу грамматику и стилистику (наведите курсор для просмотра):</sup>

> <sup>Как люд<strike>ей</strike> из бывшего Союза называют<strike>сья</strike> сейчас?</sup>

<sup>правильно либо</sup>

> <sup>Как люд**И** из бывшего Союза называют**СЯ** сейчас?</sup>

<sup>либо</sup>

> <sup>Как люд**ЕЙ** из бывшего Союза называю**Т** сейчас?</sup>

> <sup>Фразу "Люди из бывшего Советского Союза" **неу**добно использовать , когда
>  хотите назвать эту группу. Также, когда хотите **назвать** одного
>  человека, котор**ЫЙ** жил в Союзе, ***фраза*** "Человек из бывшего Союза" ***звучит***
>  неуклюж**Е**. Должно быть одно слово для этого. Мы с друз**Ь**ям**И** используем
>  слово "совок," но это просто из-за того, что я начинал это слово так
>  использовать. Я знаю, что "совок" это человек, который верит в систему
>  коммунизма, и это слово не очень приличное. Но ***на мой взгляд*** "совок"
>  звучит правильно, **потому что** слово начинается ***с сочетания букв, как в
>  слове*** "советский", ***и имеет окончание существительного***.</sup>

Comment: пожалуйста, не используйте ответ для того, чтобы поправить грамматические ошибки автора поста - если только эти ошибки не влияют каким-то образом на сам ответ. В 99% случаев достаточно просто поправить ошибки в самом вопросе - а автор будет смотреть и учиться.

Comment: если это противоречит правилам, уточните пожалуйста, каким именно, или как минимум поясните логику такого требования... ну и вы как бы сейчас удалили то, что было написано с лучшими намерениями, и для того, чтобы автор САМ исправил свой пост, при желании, а в мой адрес достаточно было просто сделать замечание на будущее, ничего не удаляя... если окажется, что это не противоречит правилам, текст будет восстановлен

Comment: Правило очень простое - ответ должен касаться вопроса. Совершенно нормально иногда указать на ошибку, но если половина текста - это грамматические разъяснения по поводу того, как написан ответ - это информационный шум для тех, кто придёт пост позже, когда ответ уже будет поправлен. Если вы считаете, что отредактировать вопрос недостаточно - в 99% случаев комментария будет достаточно.

Comment: вы хотели сказать "логика очень простая", потому что, как я понимаю из вашего ответа, правила такого не существует, иначе вы привели бы цитату или дали ссылку... поэтому я восстанавливаю текст, но идя на встречу вашим пожеланиям, делаю его менее "шумным"

Comment: Поймите, всё, что не касается ответа на вопрос - офф-топ. Если вы хотите более развёрнутого ответа (или уверены в неправомерностям моих действий) -задайте, пожалуйста, вопрос на мете - наверное будет полезным разъяснить.

Comment: разъяснение на мете опять же будет носить характер рекомендации, и я не ощущаю потребности в выяснении для себя этого вопроса... комментарий по грамматике я добавил только для пользы автора и/или других читателей

Comment: Вы не совсем правильно трактуете правила, их наполнение и применительную практику.

Comment: кроме того лично я не люблю, когда мои комментарии редактируют без моего ведома и спроса у меня, как сделали вы например, (хотя я не против исправления ошибок), именно поэтому я не стал самовольно редактировать текст вопроса автора, это может быть расценено как акт высокомерия

Comment: На моей памяти не было ни одного случая, когда бы автор поста обиделся бы на то, что в его посте были исправлены грамматические ошибки - к тому же, исправления проходят аппрув.

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка I mainly use English to communicate on this site and people who are better versed in English than me correct mistakes in my answers all the time, for which I am extremely grateful. This is in accordance with the general SE policy, which lists grammar and spelling mistakes as the number one reason for editing questions and answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing

Comment: @Quassnoi I believe this is a bit different because here we have a non-native speaker whose mistakes are not due to sloppiness or poor education. Anyway with regard to feeling offended it was my assumption and since asking each and every person is impractical i chose to be on the safe side, not least because of the sheer volume of the mistakes

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще выражение "Из республик", которое достаточно часто применяется к приезжим из бывшего СССР (но не России), причем переехавшим уже после распада СССР. Выражение это имеет немного пренебрежительную и даже унизительную окраску в отношении тех, к кому оно применяется.